# How to repaint a JLabel?

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator, repaint

I have a problem with my calculator which i want to make in Java.
I have a JLabel which shoulds display over buttons inputted numbers. My problem is every time the user press a button, the frame get not repainted, but it opens a new JFrame with the updated JLabel text. I think the new JFrame belongs to the new in my generateCalculatorFrame()-method, but I dont know how to repaint my JFrame rightly. I have searched for solutions about two hours and asked a more experienced programmer than me, but he also couldnt found a solution.

Here is my code:

```
package com.decase.taschenrechner;
```

public class Calculator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Erzeugt das CalculatorFrame
    CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame();

    // Legt die Funktionen der Buttons fest
    ButtonEvents.generateButtonEvents();
}
```

}

```
package com.decase.taschenrechner;
```

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CalculatorFrame {

```
public static JFrame generateCalculatorFrame ()
{
  JFrame calculatorFrame = new JFrame("Taschenrechner");
  // Legt die Größe des Fensters fest
  calculatorFrame.setSize(450, 600);
  // Schließt das Fenster beim Klick auf "X"
  calculatorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  // Fügt das calculatorPanel dem calculatorFrame hinzu
  calculatorFrame.add(CalculatorPanel.generateCalculatorPanel());
  // Setzt die Position des Fensters auf Null, also auf die Mitte des Bildschirms
  calculatorFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  // Setzt die Sichtbarkeit des Fensters auf sichtbar
  calculatorFrame.setVisible(true);
  return calculatorFrame;
}
```

}

```
package com.decase.taschenrechner;
```

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CalculatorPanel {

```
public static JPanel generateCalculatorPanel ()
{
  // Erzeugt ein JPanel auf dem die anderen beiden Panel dargestellt werden
  JPanel calculatorPanel = new JPanel();
  // Legt das Layout des  JPanels fest
  calculatorPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(calculatorPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
  // Legt die Farbe des JPanels fest
  calculatorPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
  // Legt das Layout des  JPanels fest
  calculatorPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
  calculatorPanel.add(CalculatorDisplay.generateCalculatorDisplay());
  calculatorPanel.add(generateButtonPanel());
  return calculatorPanel;       
}

public static JPanel generateButtonPanel ()
{
  // Erzeugt ein neues JPanel auf dem die Buttons dargestellt werden
  JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
  // Legt die Farbe des JPanels fest
  buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
  // Legt das Layout des  JPanels fest
  buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));
  // Fügt die einzelnen Buttons dem JPanel hinzu
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonOne);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonTwo);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonThree);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonDeleteLast);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonFour);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonFive);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonSix);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonPlus);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonSeven);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonEight);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonNine);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonMinus);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonDeleteAll);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonComma);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonNull);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonMultiply);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonBracketRight);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonBracketLeft);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonEqual);
  buttonPanel.add(CalculatorButtons.buttonDivide);
  return buttonPanel;
}
```

}

```
package com.decase.taschenrechner;
```

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CalculatorDisplay {

```
public static String displayText = "";

public static JLabel generateCalculatorDisplay ()
{
    // Erstellt ein neues JLabel
    JLabel calculatorDisplay = new JLabel();
    // Legt die Größe des JLabels fest
    calculatorDisplay.setSize(50, 50);
    // Legt die Hintergrundfarbe des JLabels fest
    calculatorDisplay.setOpaque(true);
    calculatorDisplay.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    // Legt die Schriftgröße des JLabels fest
    calculatorDisplay.setFont(calculatorDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
    // Legt die Schriftfarbe des JLabels fest
    calculatorDisplay.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    // Legt den Text des JLabels fest
    calculatorDisplay.setText(displayText);
    // Gibt das JLabel zurück
    return calculatorDisplay;
}
```

}

```
package com.decase.taschenrechner;
```

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ButtonEvents {

```
public static void generateButtonEvents() {

    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonNull fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonNull.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "0";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });

    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonOne fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "1";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });

    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonTwo fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "2";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonThree fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonThree.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "3";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonFour fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonFour.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "4";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonFive fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonFive.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "5";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonSix fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonSix.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "6";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonSeven fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonSeven.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "7";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonEight fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonEight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "8";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonNine fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonNine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "9";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonComma fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonComma.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + ".";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonPlus fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonPlus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "+";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonMinus fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonMinus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "-";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonMultiply fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonMultiply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "x";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonDivide fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonDivide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "\u00F7";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonBracketRight fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonBracketRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "(";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonBracketLeft fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonBracketLeft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + ")";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonEqual fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonEqual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText + "=";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonDeleteLast fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonDeleteLast.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                CalculatorDisplay.displayText = CalculatorDisplay.displayText.substring(0,
                        CalculatorDisplay.displayText.length() - 1);
                CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
        }
    });
    // Legt die Funktionen von buttonDeleteAll fest
    CalculatorButtons.buttonDeleteAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CalculatorDisplay.displayText = "";
            CalculatorFrame.generateCalculatorFrame().repaint();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: I didn't look at your code (there's way too much of it) but usually you just call `setText()` on the label and it updates itself.  I've written programs like this before and that's all I did.  (See the help FAQ for a *Minimal* Verifiable Example program.)

Comment: You have pointed the problem rightly. You are creating new instances of the JFrame and the main JPanel each time you call your methods generate. Why don't you create the instances just once and store a reference to them? I think that you are trying unsuccessfully to use what seems a Singleton pattern.

Comment: Hey markspace, thank you for your answer, that seems to help me. Thank you too, RubioRic, but I recognize i didnt explain my problem rightly^^ I had already created instances in a previous attempt, but this version didnt updated my JLabel text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about this: I think the new JFrame belongs to the new in my generateCalculatorFrame()-method. The thing is whenever you call that method a NEW frame will be generate -> a new object. What you want to do (i think) is to modify your current object(the current frame). Also, you don't need to create a new panel or a new label, you just want to update the existing ones.

Easiest solution would be the Singleton "pattern" (http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples). Make calculatorFrame, calculatorPanel and calculatorDisplay static variables and instead of "generating new objects" use the same one, generated only on the first call of the method.

```
private static JLabel calculatorDisplay;
    public static JLabel generateCalculatorDisplay ()
    {
      if(calculatorDisplay != null)
            {
                //tiny hack so i could quickly check it works. 
                //better move it to an update display method
                calculatorDisplay.setText(displayText);
                return calculatorDisplay;
            }
            calculatorDisplay = new JLabel();
            // Legt die Größe des JLabels fest
            calculatorDisplay.setSize(50, 50);
            // Legt die Hintergrundfarbe des JLabels fest
            calculatorDisplay.setOpaque(true);
            calculatorDisplay.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            // Legt die Schriftgröße des JLabels fest
            calculatorDisplay.setFont(calculatorDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
            // Legt die Schriftfarbe des JLabels fest
            calculatorDisplay.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            // Legt den Text des JLabels fest
            calculatorDisplay.setText(displayText);
            // Gibt das JLabel zurück
            return calculatorDisplay;
    }
```

This was a quick mock. Hope this was the functionality you were looking for.
[updated_display_label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nBDA.png)

Comment: Hey, thank you, I created a update-method with calculatorDisplay.setText(displayText);                                                                                                                       and called it in my ActionEvent. I also made calculatorFrame, calculatorPanel and calculatorDisplay static variables again. It works fine!